# UART make sure to prevent data loss; choppy binary transmission

Tags: serial, uart, data-transfer, pi-pico

If I use UART to send sensor data from a Pi Pico to another computer (received via `/dev/tinyUSB0`), does the "default protocol" have any sort of error correction? I guess I don't need to worry over flipped bits, but potentially bytes could be dropped? So how would I go about this. Is there a simple protocol layer that I can add on top? Do I just define my own start/stop words to make sure the receiver can recover from lost data?

Like, the simplest idea I can come up with is to encode the data so that it only uses the 7 least significant bits in each byte, and then I can mark frame start and frame stop with 0x80 and 0x81. But I wonder if I'm reinventing the wheel? Or I just encode numbers as ASCII string representations and insert newlines?

For instance, here is my attempt with a frame bound 0x80, 0x81:

```
00000000  80 2e 50 29 2d 81 80 33  5a 2b 64 81 80 30 5d 2c  |..P)-..3Z+d..0],|
00000010  25 81 80 2f 4c 29 14 81  80 33 7e 2d 49 81 80 2e  |%../L)...3~-I...|
00000020  1e 29 34 81 80 32 80 2f  35 2c 46 81 80 2d 27 28  |.)4..2./5,F..-'(|
00000030  81 80 37 0e 30 2a 81 80  2b 25 27 2d 81 80 35 0b  |..7.0*..+%'-..5.|
00000040  2c 57 81 80 32 39 2d 3f  81 80 2c 4a 26 78 81 80  |,W..29-?..,J&x..|
00000050  39 6c 2f 73 81 80 2c 55  29 01 81 80 32 5f 2a 1e  |9l/s..,U)...2_*.|
00000060  81 80 34 53 2d 71 81 80  2b 73 26 6c 81 80 38 2a  |..4S-q..+s&l..8*|
00000070  2f 41 81 80 2d 09 28 73  81 80 32 6e 2a 10 81 80  |/A..-.(s..2n*...|
00000080  35 0c 2e 25 81 80 2b 46  26 4f 81 80 38 25 2f 2e  |5..%..+F&O..8%/.|
00000090  81 80 2e 26 29 21 81 80  31 2a 29 81 80 35 53 2e  |...&)!..1*)..5S.|
000000a0  53 81 80 2a 6f 26 69 81  80 38 81 80 2b 26 76 81  |S..*o&i..8..+&v.|
000000b0  80 35 73 2c 72 81 80 31  2b 39 81 80 30 2c 2c 7e  |.5s,r..1+9..0,,~|
000000c0  81 80 2e 02 28 55 81 80  33 66 2e 40 81 80 2d 52  |....(U..3f.@..-R|
000000d0  28 72 81 80 32 5e 2b 40  81 80 2f 79 2c 12 81 80  |(r..2^+@../y,...|
000000e0  2e 2d 28 75 81 80 33 3a  2d 61 81 80 2d 7b 28 64  |.-(u..3:-a..-{(d|
000000f0  81 80 32 6b 2b 54 81 80  30 0a 81 80 33 33 2d 3c  |..2k+T..0...33-<|
00000100  81 80 2e 4b 29 39 81 80  33 0f 2b 28 81 80 2f 29  |...K)9..3.+(../)|
00000110  47 81 80 33 2d 57 81 80  2e 2a 29 22 81 80 33 31  |G..3-W...*)"..31|
```

If you look at the hexdump carefully, you'll note that the payload between 0x80 and 0x81 is usually 4 bytes -- which it should be -- but occasionally bytes are missing. What could be the cause of this? Also if I follow the hexdump on the screen, it stutters a lot, the speed is very irregular. In comparison, if I output ASCII text, it is very fluent. Perhaps my Python code is bad? Hex output:

```py
    numTouch = 2
    # 2 bytes per sensor value, one start byte,
    # one stop byte
    bufSz = numTouch * 2 + 2
    buf = bytearray(bufSz) 
    buf[0]         = 0b10000000
    buf[bufSz - 1] = 0b10000001
    touchVals      = [0, 0] # polled later

    # loop
    while True:
      bi = 1
      for idx in range(numTouch):
        touchVal = ...
        senseHi  = (touchVal >> 7) & 0b1111111
        senseLo  =  touchVal       & 0b1111111
        buf[bi] = senseHi
        bi += 1
        buf[bi] = senseLo
        bi += 1

      uart.write(buf)
```

versus this, which outputs fluently:

```py
    text = "A: {}, B: {}\n".format(touchVals[0], touchVals[0])
    buf1 = bytes(text, "ascii")
    uart.write(buf1)
```

Here is a visual comparison of the dataflow, showing the problematic binary data vs the straight forward text data:

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit:** This difference led me to believe that UART (or CircuitPython) expects newline characters flushing. If I change the stop byte from 0x81 to 0x0A, suddenly the hex dump reception is smooth. Could somebody explain this, please? Can I explicitly flush after a write? The API doesn't seem to provide such function.

Comment: `I don't need to worry over flipped bits` ... why not?

Comment: @jsotola well, wouldn't that be the minimum requirement of the serial bus to work at all?

Comment: Not Pi specific.

Comment: @joan can you stop voting to close every second question of mine? It's very annoying. I'm trying to solve a problem with CircuitPython, a Pi Pico and UART. Look, I also have 64K reputation on stackoverflow, I know how the Q&A sites work. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps related topic (seems similar problems of dropped data): https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=134752#p897104

Comment: @jsotola I read now that there is no clock sync or such, so one could even receive with the Tx pin disconnected, so you are probably right, I should also prepare for flipped bits and add a CRC.

Comment: @joan is correct, developing an error correcting serial protocol is not a Raspberry Pi specific task

Comment: Your flashing display may look neet but it is not stable enough to read. I cannot figure out how you can get 4 bytes between two consecutive 8 bit locations, can you explain? Go online and study a few tutorials on async communication and how a UART or USART works. You ask "does the "default protocol" have any sort of error correction?" What device? You might also want to do a bit of reading on protocols and how they work, it is a lot more then connecting a few wires.  You can program a UART to do 7 bits and also even/odd parity if you want. I normally do 115200, N, 8, 1.

Comment: Back in the early 1970s protocols were developed for reliable data transfer.  This was before internet or even microprocessor OS.

Comment: You should absolutely worry about flipped bits. Every serial protocol, from XMODEM to Arduino bootloader, has some sort of checksums and ACK/NACK responses to ensure reliable data transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "dropping" of bytes happens because not all byte values are directly passed through when reading from `/dev/tty...`. This depends on the [line discipline](https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyACM1
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
min = 0; time = 0;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-opost
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo
```

Here `line = 0` indicates the canonical mode, in which many of the ASCII characters below 0x20 (and some above) have special meaning for controlling the editing buffer.

- 0x03 : intr = ^C
- 0x04 : eof = ^D
- 0x05 : enquiry = ^E
- 0x0D : CR, carriage return
- 0x11 : start = ^Q, device control 1
- 0x12 : rprnt = ^R, device control 2
- 0x13 : stop = ^S, device control 3
- 0x15 : kill = ^U
- 0x16 : lnext = ^V
- 0x17 : werase = ^W
- 0x1A : susp = ^Z
- 0x1C : quit = ^\
- 0x7F : DEL, delete

To avoid that, when configuring `stty`, one has to choose the `raw` (pass through) line discipline.

A better approach is to use a dedicated serial communication library. For example, in my case, rather than open the stream as

```scala
val device = "/dev/ttyACM1" 
new java.io.FileInputStream(device)
```

One can get a serial connection that avoids tty processing, for example using the jSerialComm library:

```scala
val device = "/dev/ttyACM1" 
val ports  = com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.getCommPorts()
val port   = ports.find(_.getSystemPortPath == device).get
val opened = port.openPort()
require (opened)
port.getInputStreamWithSuppressedTimeoutExceptions
```

This again wraps in a `java.io.InputStream` with read-blocking behaviour. As a result, no bytes are dropped, no newline is needed to flush.

[image: fluently running input with binary stream]